# Start And Stop Method Automatically

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to start my `sensor reading method` after 10 seconds and stop it after say 5 minutes. This is the code for the same.

```
case R.id.btn_pos_poll_side: {

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                //Delay Runner Here
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        side_output.setText("Delayed Data Collection");
                        //Start reading LIGHT SENSOR Data, Handle Null Light Sensor Data
                        if (LightSensor != null || mProximity != null || mAccelerometer != null || mGyroscope != null) {

                            //listen to light sensor.
                            mySensorManager.registerListener(
                                    MultiSensorListener,
                                    LightSensor,
                                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

                            //listen to proximity sensor.
                            mySensorManager.registerListener(
                                    MultiSensorListener,
                                    mProximity,
                                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

                            //listen accelerometer, note this has 3-axes.
                            mySensorManager.registerListener(
                                    MultiSensorListener,
                                    mAccelerometer,
                                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                            //listen gyroscope, note this has 3-axes.
                            mySensorManager.registerListener(
                                    MultiSensorListener,
                                    mGyroscope,
                                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

                            //print output text
                            side_output.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h3> ----- Data Collection Session Starts Here -----</h3>"));

                        } else {
                            side_output.setText("No Sensor Found!");
                        }
                    }
                }, 10000);

                final Handler closeHandler = new Handler();
                //Data Sender Runner Here
                closeHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Button stopCollection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop_poll_side);
                        stopCollection.performClick();
                    }
                }, 120000);
                break;
            }
```

However this never works and even the data collected is somewhat corrupt (new data is concatenated to previous data).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**Edit**: Some more details. I want to start it after 10 seconds from when I have pressed the button and stop it after say 2 minutes. This happens only once unless I press the button again.

Added: **Stop Button Logic**

```
case R.id.btn_stop_poll_side: {
                // remove sensor listener
                mySensorManager.unregisterListener(MultiSensorListener,
                        LightSensor);
                mySensorManager.unregisterListener(MultiSensorListener,
                        mProximity);
                mySensorManager.unregisterListener(MultiSensorListener,
                        mAccelerometer);
                mySensorManager.unregisterListener(MultiSensorListener,
                        mGyroscope);
                side_output.append("\n" + sensorReading);
                /*
                    Reading data and writing to Dropbox!
                 */
                new DropboxTask(side_output, "Back Pocket Data Reading", sensorReading).execute();
                break;
            }
```

Comment: do you want the start and stop to happen for life time or for a limited no. of times?

Comment: @DarshanMiskin I want to start it after 10 seconds from when I have pressed the button and stop it after say 2 minutes. This happens only once unless I press the button again.

Comment: your handlers seem logically correct except that the stop method will be called just 10 seconds prior to 2 minutes. what exactly is the issue which you are facing?

Comment: First, it crashes! Second, I think the thread never get killed and whenever I trigger the button the second time,the have the data of the previous click session.

Comment: if its crashing, then maybe logs would help here. Also, you accidentally ate a word or two, what has the data of previous session?

Comment: I mean the data of the previous session is getting added to the data of the new session, a behavior I absolutely don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user presses the button the first time:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do what you need to do
    }
}
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10_000 /* Wait 10 seconds */);
```

When the user presses the button the second time:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Stop what you want to stop
    }
}
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2*60*1000 /* Wait 2 minutes */);
```

This has to be done in the `onClick` of your button:

First define a private boolean like called `isButtonAlreadyClicked = false`.

Now:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(!isButtonAlreadyClicked) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Do what you need to do
                }
            }
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10_000 /* Wait 10 seconds */);
            isButtonAlreadyClicked = true;
        } else {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Stop what you want to stop
                }
            }
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2*60*1000 /* Wait 2 minutes */);
            isButtonAlreadyClicked = false;
        }
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to prevent the runnable to be run while it is waiting, just make sure to declare the handler and your runnables outside of your method (inside your class), so that you can do (for example):

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(firstRunnable);
mHandler.removeCallbacks(secondRunnable);
```

In that way it won't run the Runnables anymore.

Comment: I have a confusion. Does this `postDelayed()` method somehow start in a new thread that needs to be explicitly stopped? Or is it just like `Thread.sleep()`?

Comment: No, it won't sleep. It will just wait like "in background" for the specified amount of miliseconds, and then do what's inside your runnable. It will be done on the thread which you created the handler on. Again, it won't block.

Comment: Fact is, how do I kill this thread. When I trigger this button again, it so happens that my data (collected in the previous click session) gets added to the new session. I am editing the question with the data collection logic, maybe that's where my problem is.

Comment: It is not a thread. What you can do, is create a new thread, and then call `yourThread.join();` on the main thread, so that your UI is frozen until the thread is stopped, or you simply create a new boolean, which will be checked in your thread every time some data is to be checked, so that the thread will just exit if the boolean is true. (Just write `if(yourBoolean) return;`)